# tuareg-mode customization for emacs

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

Since I installed the last tuareg package (*2.0.10*), some things really annoy me and I can't find how to change them back to their previous setup :

```
let print_enum = 
  let c = ref 0 in
  fun f ->
  List.iter (fun e a
                 b c ->
    ) l
```

Here I'd like to have :

```
let print_enum = 
  let c = ref 0 in
  fun f ->
    List.iter (fun e a
      b c ->
    ) l
```

I couldn't find the indentation for `fun f ->` nor for

```
fun_app a b
  c d
```

in the customization menu.

Comment: How about diffing the old one from the new one and see what changed, or just use the older version that contains the behavior you prefer?

Comment: Because the mode completely changed between my previous version and the new one and I like to keep my packages updated. And mostly because I don't understand why these features disappeared (I mean, having the arguments of an application being aligned with the first argument gives you a code with a huuuuge blank when you go to a newline).

Comment: The file `CHANGES` describes what is new and the first line looks very interesting:  https://github.com/ocaml/tuareg/blob/master/CHANGES  Perhaps you could type `M-x describe-variable RET tuareg-indent-align-with-first-arg RET` and see if that is what is causing you the behavior you wish to avoid.  Since it is a variable, you can probably customize it to your liking.  The `CHANGES` file only deals with versions 2.0.9 and 2.0.10.  If you were running version 2.0.9 before updating your package, then the list of items to check is relatively short.

Comment: Oh, ok. I will look at that. I had a version older than the 2.0.9, sadly.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for my specific case, it works for `printf "%s %s" s1 s2` if `s2` is on another line it will get aligned according to `printf` and not `s1` anymore. But for `fun e a b c ->` nothing changed. And I still can't find why `fun f ->` and `List.iter` are aligned.

Comment: If after a reasonable period of time you do not obtain an answer in this forum, then you may wish to consider submitting an issue on Github to the maintainer and/or break-out the old diff-utility and compare your previous version to the current version.  You can also browse through the Github revision histories to see exactly what changes were made, and when those changes occurred.  I'm sorry that I couldn't be of more of assistance.

Comment: No, you were of great assistance, thank you very much. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use `ocp-indent` instead of the built-in indentation of tuareg:

- https://www.typerex.org/ocp-indent.html
- https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent

Indentation customization can be very intuitively. You can check out the sample configuration file for `ocp-indent`:
https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocp-indent/blob/master/.ocp-indent

Comment: I thought I already had ocp-indent. :D Thanks, it works well and easy to customize !